# Signal recovery in Frequency domain?

Tags: signal-processing, software-defined-radio

I am writing a MATLAB program in which I am doing OFDM symbol transmission through Fading channel:

```
Ncp=15;
Nfft=128 ; % size of fft
x = complex(randn(1,128), randn(1,128)); % the signal to be transmitted 
IFFT_Data =ifft(x); % OFDM Modulation
Tx =  [IFFT_Data((128-Ncp+1):128), IFFT_Data];
h=rand(1,600); % the fading channel 
y = conv(Tx,h); % transmission through channel 
received_signal = fft(y); % OFDM demodualtion
```

From this point I want to reconstruct my transmitted data as you see when we use FFT. That means we are in frequency doamin, right? Then we need also to take FFT, now we are obliged to work in frequency domain. Can you tell me how I can reconstruct my transmitted data x?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the FFT output as containing the received data modulated onto 128 (FFT size) different carrier frequencies. Those 128 signals are then demodulated separately to yield 128 symbols. Each symbol can contain 2-bits for example, if QPSK modulation is considered. See the diagram below from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing):

[image]

To understand this a bit better take a look at the Transmission System:

Notice that the serial input signal is parallelised, encoded and applied to different bins in the IFFT. This effectively "modulates" the encoded data onto different carriers corresponding to the IFFT bin frequencies. Finally this signal may be modulated onto a radio carrier.

[image]

Comment: @ akellyirl : please check the matlab code in the top and then you can understand what's exactly my problem , at receiver side i have a larage Number of multipath coefficients (y signal) ?

Comment: when my input is only  1 by 128 ?

Comment: @user3070338 I have read your code. Your problem is that you have not encoded your data and you have not decoded your data. That's why I put up diagrams for the OFDM path; so that you might understand the problem and fix it. If you're looking for me to write your Matlab code for you, I don't have the time for that.

Comment: @ akellyirl : thank you for interest i know what is exactly my problem (is not about encoding and decoding data as you said), again my problem is about a size of transmitting data is 1 by 128 , and for my received signal y is 1 by 742 ! , h represent multipath fading channel